# Why is py.exe using an older version of Python when double-clicking?

Tags: python, windows

I usually run my scripts in a command prompt, but I tried double-clicking it to use the Python launcher in order to test something. Weirdly, I've discovered that while doing `py script.py` in the command prompt will run the script under the version I want, 3.10, if I were to double-click the file it will run it with 3.8, my old version.

I don't think I need to keep Python 3.8 anymore and I can probably just uninstall it and solve this, but before I do I'm curious as to why this is even happening in the first place, and is there a way I can change what version its using?

EDIT: Here's [a short gif](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/327195739346173962/1060133672143036426/explorer_2023-01-04_03-51-58.gif) to show it clearly. From what I can tell, I think when I run `py` in the command prompt its using the path to `C:\Windows\py.exe`, but when I double-click its opening with `C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\py.exe`. I'm still not really sure how to make it use the right one though, even if I remove the latter from my PATH it does the same thing.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#customizing-default-python-versions

Comment: I've told Windows to use the `C:\Windows\py.exe` to open `.py` files from now on, as well as adding a `py.ini` file in *both* directories specifying that the default version should be 3.10, but when I open `.py` files in the explorer it still runs 3.8 just as before.

Comment: Strike that, it does actually seem to work now. Not sure why it didn't at first, but I guess this is solved for now.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using updated pip so that time it's need that python version or if you have made py into exe with any version basically it depends on that one also otherwise it will work simply.

Hope this will help you.